# css / padding on emails

Tags: css, email

Most of the elements on my email page will line up on all email clients correctly if I give the tr and td correct height / widths and tr display inline-block. However on a certain block im having troubles getting the elements to line up without a gap / space between elements.

[image]

The first image is the rounded corners on the left and I got it to line up with the block next to it by giving the td / tr and smaller width than that of the img thats inside. However I cannot do this to the other blocks or else they just get smaller all together.

I can change my structure if needed but right now I've kinda limited myself by putting all elements as td's in one tr instead of each element being a tr

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <img left corners />
  </td>
  <td>
      180
  </td>
  <td>
     22
  </td>
  <td>
    <img right corners />
  </td>
</tr>
```

fiddle away! http://jsfiddle.net/Qh7En/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick comment. The left and right rounded corner images where above the middle parts and in different amounts between gmail and outlook. However I completely fixed that and everything is lined up perfectly by adding align="top" to the <img> inside the td. also by removing the spaces between the td and img and between each tr. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. :)

I basically altered the `display` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh7En/7/

Also, it would probably be better if you didn't use inline CSS. Consider making a class instead.

Comment: well its an email so I believe it has to be all inline. but thanks for the answer too!!

Comment: Wow thank you! I think I didn't even consier to use display table cause of email support but I checked it in outlook and gmail and it works, although the padding is perfect on gmail, its off 1 px in outlook. Still, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing this in all browsers?

It looks like a typical issue with images always having padding, unless you specifically tell CSS to remove it.  Something as simple as adding "img { padding:0px }" to the CSS.

Comment: good point. Although while this would work on a website I tried it with no avail on outlook emails. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to fix this.

One is to comment out the white space between the elements.

```
   .....
   </td><!--
--><td
   ....
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Qh7En/8/

Comment: I wish I could also give you the answer as well but 9997 was first with a working answer. Im not sure if display table is supported by all email clients so maybe I should just get rid of white-space as well? But this is something that I find interesting and boggles my mind that whitespace that normally would mean nothing on a website actually creates space in emails. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @mike In this situation removing the white space is the safest way to go when dealing with different email clients and environments.